# Can we change the off-topic reason text?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

The main off topic reason (the generic one that every site has) currently reads this on this site:

> This question does not appear to be about open source software, within the scope defined in the help center.

Two questions:

1. Why does it read this in the first place? As far as I can tell, the Area 51 proposal scoped this site so that it *wasn't* limited to just software - so why does the OT reason say it is?
2. Can we change it? It shouldn't mention anything about software, merely saying open source would be enough.

Comment: @Zizouz212 Indeed a dupe, hadn't realised it existed

Comment: In that case, let's redirect people :)